# JSP　～ を型に解決できません　というエラーが出る

Tags: jsp, arraylist

現在下記ソースのように実装しているのですが、
ArrayList を型に解決できません。
Iterator を型に解決できません。
というエラーが出ています。

```html
<%    
          ArrayList<String> cont =  (ArrayList)request.getAttribute("list");
          Iterator<String> itr = cont.iterator();
%>
```

リストを取得したいと思い、[このサイト](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10875325/scriptlet-in-jsp-accessing-request-objects)を参考に実装しようとしたところエラーが発生しました。
エラーを消す方法の分かる方がいましたらご教授お願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

importをしていません

```html
<%@ page import="java.util.ArrayList" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.Iterator" %>
```